# Splitting dictionary depending on key name

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I need to split up into smaller dictionaries depending on the key name using the values from an array:

```
dict = {'1_100': 50, '1_102': 100, '2_100': 150, '2_102': 200, '3_100': 50, '3_102': 100, ...}

narray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]
```

I am trying to split up the dictionary depending on the first number of the key

So far I have done the following:

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    for t in narray:
        if str(t) + "_" in str(dict.keys()):
```

I am unsure how to do the actual splitting part and ensuring that a new dictionary is made when it comes across new number in the *"X_"* key. Note there are a different number of each keys, so splitting every nth number would not work

I want to ideally end up with

```
dict1 = {'1_100': 50, '1_102': 100, ...}
dict2 = {'2_100': 50, '2_102': 100, ...}
dict3 = {'3_100': 50, '3_102': 100, ...}
dictN = {'N_100': 50, 'N_102': 100, ...}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are the numbers in `narray` all successive positive integers?

Comment: @Reti43 yes they are successive positive integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dcts = {str(n): {} for n in narray}
for k, v in dct.items():
    dcts[k.split('_')[0]][k] = v
dcts = list(dcts.values())
```

`dct` is your initial dictionary, `dcts` is a list of dictionaries (you may want to remove the empty ones).

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'1_100': 50, '1_102': 100, '2_100': 150, '2_102': 200, '3_100': 50, '3_102': 100}

for k,v in data.items():
    name = "dict" + k.split("_")[0]
    d = globals().get(name, {})
    d.update({k:v})
    globals()[name] = d

print(dict1)
print(dict2)
print(dict3)
```

Result:

{'1_100': 50, '1_102': 100}

{'2_100': 150, '2_102': 200}

{'3_100': 50, '3_102': 100}

Comment: Adding names like that to scope is a bad idea, because you'll have to fetch them with a similar hack when you need them. It's much better to either create a list of dicts or dicts of dicts.

Comment: Yes I know, I just wrote the code in such a way to make it similar to his example

Comment: HI thank you for this. I must go do some reading on the global function, as I have not used that before

Comment: @Momo My recommendation is not to use them, but to create a variable results that has as key the name and as value the d. 
reusults[name] = d ; print(results["dict1"])